# How to fully reset QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows-10

I use QGIS 3.6 on Windows 10 and I want to reset it. 
I tried this through Setting-Options-System-Reset user Interface to default settings. I uninstalled and installed again, but still there are some saved features.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Edited! Windows

Comment: just start with a new profile: settings->User Profiles->New Profile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete the config directory.

**Windows:**

```
%LocalAppData%\QGIS  

%AppData%\QGIS
```

**Linux:**

```
/home/USERNAME/.local/share/QGIS
```

**Macintosh:**

```
/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

Comment: Cool! Please accept/upvote my answer above to reflect that when you can :)

Comment: Had already done that :)

Comment: Ah, it is still showing as no green checkmark, so not accepted, just upvoted. Could you check again? Thanks!

Comment: something new for me, now done for sure!