# Editing problem after long time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing

I'm using QGIS 3.26 and after a long time editing SHP I get problems. When I want to split the polygon by split features from point 1 to point 2 and 3 (image), after clicking on point 1 the function wants to split the polygon, which is completely out of my interest.

Also, I can't even edit the vertex anymore.

I have to restart QGIS and then it works fine for a while but after a while the same problem again.

I also had this problem in version 3.16, but this problem did not exist in version 2.18

[image]

Comment: Try to save your layers as geopackage: does the problem persist? Did you check the data for geometry/topology errors?

Comment: The first thing I would check are for geometry/topology errors in your shapefile as Babel suggests.  I would also check your snapping tolerances and settings.  You might try saving your edits more frequently too.   If these are all fine I'd move the shapefile to a new project and see if the issues continue there.  Lastly if this happens to multiple shapefiles I would reset your QGIS application data folder, which doesn't change during updates.   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349581/how-to-fully-reset-qgis

Comment: is the shape file being accessed by some other computer process or user?

Comment: It helped to save the shapefile to a geopackage. This shapefile/geopackage is only used by me. For check geometry/ topology errors can i use "Check geometries"?